# Amazon SageMaker Model Registry / Pipelines - how to manually set a Stage for a given Model Version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

This might be a **very** specific question, but I will try anyway.

I want to explicitly set the Stage column in Model registry for a given Model Version:

[image]

This picture comes from the documentation and it gets set only when you run the example SageMaker Projects MLOps Templates they provide. When I create the `Model Package` (i.e. `Model Version`) manually, the column remains empty. How do I set it? What API do I call?

[Additionally, the documentation on browsing the model version history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-deploy-history.html) has a following sentence

[image]

How do we send that exact event ("Deployed to stage XYZ") manually?

I already thoroughly went over all the files SageMaker MLOps Project generates (CodeBuild Builds, CodePipeline, CloudFormation, various `.py` files, SageMaker Pipeline) but could not find any direct and explicit call for that event.

I think it may be somehow connected to the Tag `sagemaker:deployment-stage` but I've already set it on `Endpoint`, `EndpointConfiguration` and `Model`, with no success. I also tried to blindly call the [UpdateModelPackage](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.update_model_package) API and set `Stage` in `CustomerMetadataProperties`. Again - no luck.

The only thing I get in that Activity tab is that given Model Version is deployed to Inference endpoint:

[image]

Comment: @RayHogan not really, but perhaps tagging it well does the trick https://repost.aws/questions/QUI07MHIlPSbSwALreeEJ28g/sagemaker-model-registry-how-to-set-the-stage-column-of-a-model-package ?

Comment: Yeah, I've deduced it no longer works. The latest SageMaker Studio UI doesn't even display the Stage column anymore, so we are going to use the custom tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the status with the `ModelApprovalStatus` parameter in the [create_model_package](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model_package) API or the [update_model_package](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.update_model_package) API

Model package state change should create an event in EventBridge (like many other SageMaker events) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automating-sagemaker-with-eventbridge.html#eventbridge-model-package, which enables you to run the automation of your choice.

In the default SageMaker Pipelines Project template, you can see the EventBridge-driven proposed logic in the CodePipeline pipeline created for deployment: you can see on top "Trigger - CloudWatchEvent".
You don't see the event source as code in the git, because the status change is expected to be done in the Studio model registry UI in that demo template.

Those EventBridge events emitted by the Model Registry can also be seen in few blogs:

- [Taming Machine Learning on AWS with MLOps: A Reference Architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/apn/taming-machine-learning-on-aws-with-mlops-a-reference-architecture/)
- [Patterns for multi-account, hub-and-spoke Amazon SageMaker model registry](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/patterns-for-multi-account-hub-and-spoke-amazon-sagemaker-model-registry/)
- [Build MLOps workflows with Amazon SageMaker projects, GitLab, and GitLab pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/build-mlops-workflows-with-amazon-sagemaker-projects-gitlab-and-gitlab-pipelines/)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I'm well aware how to change the `ModelApprovalStatus` for a given Version and how this automatically triggers the CI/CD pipeline via EventBridge. I've skimmed closely through all the files MLOps Templates create to witness all that magic. What I am looking for is a way to set the STAGE column for a given Version (i.e. `Model Package` in a `Model Package Group`). I want to see explicit (or implicit) mechanism that changes the value in that column (None -> `staging` -> `prod`). Why and when does that happen? What triggers it?

Comment: yes good point I confused Status and Stage ; let me look deeper

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue, I wanted to change the model stage but could not find where it was being done in the sample code AWS provides.

After some research and looking into the sample code I realized that it was being done in the cloud formation execution. First they add the tag

```
'sagemaker:deployment-stage': stage_config['Parameters']['StageName']
```

and then the cloud formation execution (cfnUpdate call) updates the stage and deploys.

I couldn't find another way to change the state with a call to update_model_package or other methods.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to set this field?